# Why is "do" used twice in the quotation, "do you do as the Queen has bidden"?

Tags: do

The extract is from B. Shaw's play "Caesar and Cleopatra".

> CAESAR [cutting her short] I speak to the Queen. Be
>   silent. [To Cleopatra] Is this how your servants know their
>   places? Send her away; and *do you [to the slave"] do* as the
>   Queen has bidden. [The slave lights the lamps. Meanwhile
>   Cleopatra stands hesitating, afraid of Ftatateeta].

Why does *do* appear twice?

Answer (score 12):

This is simply a more emphatic (and verbose) form of the second-person imperative: *do* + *you* + bare infinitive, which last is in this case another *do.* This form allows for extra verbal as well as physical emphasis (in performance) on the redirection of Caesar’s speech from Cleopatra to the Nubian slave; this imperative is addressed to the latter.

OED s.v. do *v.:*

> 31. *trans* As periphrastic auxiliary in imperatives.
>       **a.** With an affirmative imperative: adding emphasis or urgency to an entreaty, exhortation, or command. Also formerly (in a command) with a second personal pronoun preceding the main verb. Originally with the main verb in the imperative . . . ; from later Middle English onwards, with the main verb in the undifferentiated base form, usually taken as infinitive.
>       . . .
>       1684   J. Bunyan *Pilgrim's Progress* 2nd Pt. ii. 144   Pray do you go along with us, I will be your Conductor.
>       . . .
>       1871   E. Eggleston *Hoosier School-master* xvi. 127   Now, Shocky,..do you run ahead.

Comment: Rather than more verbose, it is more emphatic, with similar meaning to "make certain you do as the queen has bidden."

Comment: Thanks, @Wlerin; adjustment made, though  this form is *also* more verbose.

Comment: This is related to the common modern phrase, "Yes, please do!", isn't it?

Comment: To some extent, yes, @Brian. But OED categorizes that differently on the grounds that in that case *do* is *substituting* for a main verb, rather than serving as *auxiliary* to a main verb explicitly included in the construction.

Answer (score 4):

It's a misprint. See [Project Gutenberg's text](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/3329/pg3329.txt):

> CAESAR (cutting her short). I speak to the Queen. Be silent. (To
>   Cleopatra) Is this how your servants know their places? Send her away;
>   **and you** (to the slave) **do as the Queen has bidden.** (The slave lights the
>   lamps. Meanwhile Cleopatra stands hesitating, afraid of Ftatateeta.) You
>   are the Queen: send her away.

Comment: -1. As I learned to my chagrin after adopting cheap Gutenberg-based print texts for my classes, Project Gutenberg is not always to be trusted. In the present case, two Penguin print editions (single play 1951, and in *Three Plays for Puritans* 1946 with "Definitive text prepared under supervision of Dan H. Laurence") both agree with OP's version with *do* twice.

Comment: [Google's scan of the 1906 edition](https://books.google.com/books?id=lJCys80pR9wC&pg=PA23) reads "and **do you** (to the slave) **do as the Queen has bidden**". It is far more likely the Gutenberg e-text is either in error or based on a modernised version rather than that this is a misprint.

Comment: The typo in the Gutenberg edition could be a deliberate edit or a mistake in OCR scanning of a page to text. In either case, the author's text as originally published should always stand. Errors can be reported to Project Gutenberg: http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Gutenberg:Readers'_FAQ#R.26._I.27ve_found_some_obvious_typos_in_a_Project_Gutenberg_text._How_should_I_report_them.3F Suggestions about errors seem to be received well according to this forum: https://forum.librivox.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=60012

Comment: Years ago I had an online discussion with a contributor to the Gutenberg project. S/he talked about using scanners and OCR, and this was a time when OCR was pretty lousy (I don't know how much better it's gotten). If that's a possible source for Gutenberg texts, I wouldn't trust them as a source, in general.

Comment: It is a pity if it is a misprint. I took the quotation from the book "Three plays for puritans" being the 3rd volume of his collected plays. It was printed by HERBERT S. STONE & CO in Chicago.